# Repeat an image in tile, and make it rotate

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, rotation

How do I fill a website with a repeated image in tiles, just like `background-repeat: repeat;` and make it rotate using either CSS or Javascript?

To rotate a single image I can use CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-ms-keyframes spin {
    from { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}                                               

img#id {                                            
    -webkit-animation-name:             spin;  
    -webkit-animation-duration:         5s;    
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:  infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:  linear;  
    -moz-animation-name:                spin;  
    -moz-animation-duration:            5s;    
    -moz-animation-iteration-count:     infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function:     linear; 
    -ms-animation-name:                 spin;  
    -ms-animation-duration:             5s;    
    -ms-animation-iteration-count:      infinite;
    -ms-animation-timing-function:      linear; 
}
```

But I can't tell how I could do this to a repeated image, i.e. access background-image as a element or repeat a `<img>` and fill the whole page with given image like `background-repeat`.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/C9bup/4/)'s an example of a rotating single image.

Comment: What are you trying to hypnotize us? :)))

Comment: So, back to the question, what are you trying to do ? repeat images dynamically?

Comment: @Givi Repeat image, and make all of them rotate. Just like a background-repeat: repeat, but with all the images rotating like the example.

Comment: Well, according answer provided below I want to say that there is nothing complicated in programming!!! So, you want rotate/repeat images as a background of some content or just to make some animation with images?

Comment: @Givi It doesn't matter if the image is represented as a background image or a <img> as long as it fills the whole site, i.e. -like- background-repeat: repeat;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirements I did something like this, although I think it is a bad option, and it can done much better...

------- **Updated** -------
Well, i make code more cleaner...

[jsFiddle Demo updated](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/Ac5RR/13/)

```
(function () {
    var left = 0,
        top = 0,
        background = document.getElementById("background"),
        getWidth = document.width,
        getHeight = document.height,
        imageSize = 240,
        width = 960,
        height = 960,
        countPerLine = 4,
        countOfImages = 16,
        difference = 0;

    function setParameters() {
        if (getWidth > width) {
            width = getWidth;
            countPerLine = Math.floor(getWidth / imageSize);
            difference = getWidth % imageSize;
            imageSize += Math.round(difference / countPerLine);
        }
        if (getHeight > height) {
            countOfImages = Math.floor(getHeight / imageSize);
            countOfImages *= countPerLine;
        }
    }

    function setBackground() {
        for (var i = 0; i < countOfImages; i++) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");

            div.classList.add("bgr");
            div.style.width = imageSize + "px";
            div.style.height = imageSize + "px";
            div.style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";
            background.appendChild(div);

            if (i === 0) {
                div.style.left = "0px";
                div.style.top = "0px";
            } else {
                left += imageSize;
                if (left >= width) {
                    left = 0;
                    top += imageSize;
                }
                div.style.left = left + "px";
                div.style.top = top + "px";
            }
        }
    }

    setParameters();
    setBackground();
}());
```

Comment: This seems pretty hacky, but it works almost as intended. Would it be possible to calculate screen area and repeat so it'll fill it aswell? Thanks! I'll wait and see if that could be fixed/more answers until I choose the accepted answer.

Comment: @TimSæterøy I guess that yes it is possible. I'll update my answer later, when come up with a better option.

Comment: It seems to work fine in Chrome, but in Firefox it won't fill the whole page, but I'll accept it anyway, thanks :)

Comment: The error is with document.getWidth. My Firefox isn't setting it correctly, so your script is working just fine.